# Reducing chip count for an ARM embedded system

Tags: arm, ram, system, system-on-chip

It seems like a lot of devices use an ARM SoC + a RAM chip + a flash storage chip. In applications that are very space-constrained, such as ChromeCast dongles, micro drones, or wristbands, it would be very useful to combine these 3 chips into 1 or 2.

Do you know of any solution that combines these three normally-separate chips into 1 package, through either die stacking or die-sharing or some other method, in order to dramatically reduce PCB area?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by an "ARM SoC"? What sort of processor and peripherals do you need?

Comment: Simple video processing (no GPU needed). Ideally with high-bitrate i/o to/from a wifi chip (SDIO), an LCD controller (8-bit parallel pixel), & a camera (8-bit parallel pixel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking in to [POP or package-on-package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_on_package) technology. An example of combining an ARM SOC and memory using POP is the[Beagle Board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard), it uses an ARM Cortex A-8 SOC and a POP memory chip that contains NAND flash memory and RAM

Comment: That's really cool!  But, are you sure that the BeagleBoard has flash in the POP memory chip?  According to the datasheet of the OMAP3530 SOC, the POP top footprint is compatible with JEDEC DDR RAM (152ball version or 168ball version for the SOC with CBC or CBB package respectively), but the datasheet doesn't mention anything about POP flash.

Comment: Yes it was in older version of the beagle board the ram and flash where in the same IC with part number "MT29C2G24MAKLAJG-6 IT ES" (this is the on ly reference i found to the datasheet http://elcodis.com/parts/4635890/MT29C2G24MAKLAJG-6_IT_TR.html#datasheet") but it seems like that IC was discontinued at some point

Comment: The Raspberry Pi has a RAM chip piggybacked on the GPU/CPU.